# Merge MST stream Monitor into one virtual

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, displayport

I'm using a PQ321QE in conjunction with two U2412M. Unfortunately, the PQ321QE which I'm using as a main screen only supports 30Hz in SST mode so I'm forced to used it in MST mode. The issue I'm having now is that the I have two separate screens inside the PQ321QE:

[image: Layout of the screens]

How can I merge those split screens into one virtual, so that e.g. maximizing windows stretch over both screens?

Some debug info:

- nVidia Drivers
- Ubuntu 15.10
- Kernel 4.2.0-18

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6960 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected 1200x1920+5760+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1.8 connected 1920x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 349mm x 393mm
   1920x2160     60.00*+  50.00  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    23.97    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00    50.08  
   720x480       59.94    60.05  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-1.1.8 connected 1920x2160+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 349mm x 393mm
   1920x2160     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```